# A question about encapsulation and inheritence practices

Tags: c++, inheritance, encapsulation

I've heard people saying that having `protected` members kind of breaks the point of encapsulation and is not the best practice, one should design the program such that derived classes will not need to have access to `private` base class members.

---

### An example situation

Now, imagine the following scenario, a simple 8bit game, we have bunch of different objects, such as, *regular boxes* act as obstacles, *spikes*, *coins*, *moving platforms* etc. List can go on.

All of them have *x and y coordinates*, *a rectangle that specifies size of the object, and collision box*, and a *texture*. Also they can share functions like *setting position*, *rendering*, *loading the texture*, *checking for collision* etc.

But some of them also need to modify base members, e.g. boxes can be pushed around so they might need a move function, some objects may be moving by themselves or maybe some blocks change texture in-game.

Therefore a base class like `object` can really come in handy, but that would either require ton of *getters* - *setters* or having `private` members to be `protected` instead. Either way, compromises encapsulation.

---

### Given the anecdotal context, which would be a better practice:

**1.** Have a common base class with shared functions and members, declared as protected. Be able to use common functions, pass the reference of base class to non-member functions which only needs to access shared properties. But compromise encapsulation.

**2.** Have a separate class for each, declare the member variables as private and don't compromise encapsulation.

**3**. A better way that I couldn't have thought.

---

I don't think encapsulation is highly vital and probably way to go for that anecdote would be just having protected members, but my goal with this question is writing a well practiced, standard code, rather than solving that specific problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I've heard people saying that having `protected` members kind of breaks the point of encapsulation and is not the best practice..." That's not correct and at that point you should stop listening and consult a more authoritative source like [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'm going to start by saying there is not a one-size fits all answer to design. Different problems require different solutions; however there are design patterns that often may be more maintainable over time than others.

Indeed, a lot of suggestions for design make them better in a *team* environment -- but good practices are also useful for solo projects as well so that it can be easier to understand and change in the future.

Sometimes the person who needs to understand your code will be you, a year from now -- so keep that in mind

> I've heard people saying that having protected members kind of breaks the point of encapsulation

Like any tool, it can be misused; but there is nothing about `protected` access that inherently breaks encapsulation.

What defines the encapsulation of your object is the intended projected API surface area. Sometimes, that `protected` member is logically part of the surface-area -- and this is perfectly valid.

If *misused*, `protected` members can give clients access to mutable members that may break a class's intended invariants -- which would be bad. An example of this would be if you were able to derive a class exposing a `rectangle`, and were able to set the width/height to a negative value. Functions in the base class, such as `compute_area` could suddenly yield wrong values -- and cause cascading failures that should otherwise have been guarded against by better encapsulated.

**As for the design of your example in question:**

Base classes are not necessarily a bad thing, but can easily be overused and can lead to "god" classes that unintentionally expose too much functionality in an effort to share logic. Over time this can become a maintenance burden and just an overall confusing mess.

Your example sounds better suited to composition, with some smaller interfaces:

- Things like a `point` and a `vector` type would be base-types to produce higher-order compositions like `rectangle`.
- This could then be composed together to create a `model` which handles general (logical) objects in 2D space that have collision.
- intersection/collision logic can be handled from an outside utility class
- Rendering can be handled from a `renderable` interface, where any class that needs to render extends from this interface.
- intersection handling logic can be handled by an `intersectable` interface, which determines behaviors of an object on intersection (this effectively abstracts each of the game objects into raw behaviors)
- etc

Answer (score 1):

encapsulation is not a security thing, its a neatness thing (and hence a supportability, readability ..).  you have to assume that people deriving classes are basically sensible. They are after all writing programs either of their own using your base classes (so who cares), or they are writing in a team with you

Answer (score 1):

The primary purpose of ["encapsulation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) in object-oriented programming is to limit direct access to data in order to minimize dependencies, and where dependencies must exist, to express those in terms of *functions* not *data*.

This is ties in with [Design by Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) where you allow "public" access to certain functions and reserve the right to modify others arbitrarily, at any time, for any reason, even to the point of removing them, by expressing those as "protected".

That is, you could have a game object like:

```
class Enemy {
public:
  int getHealth() const;
}
```

Where the `getHealth()` function returns an `int` value expressing the health. How does it derive this value? It's not for the caller to know or care. Maybe it's byte 9 of a binary packet you just received. Maybe it's a string from a JSON object. It doesn't matter.

Most importantly because it doesn't matter you're free to change how `getHealth()` works internally without *breaking* any code that's *dependent* on it.

However, if you're exposing a public `int health` property that opens up a whole world of problems. What if that is manipulated incorrectly? What if it's set to an invalid value? How do you trap access to that property being manipulated?

It's much easier when you have `setHealth(const int health)` where you can do things like:

- clamp it to a particular range
- trigger an event when it exceeds certain bounds
- update a saved game state
- transmit an update over the network
- hook in other "observers" which might need to know when that value is manipulated

None of those things are easily implemented without encapsulation.

`protected` is not just a "get off my lawn" thing, it's an important tool to ensure that your implementation is used *correctly* and *as intended*.